# Imagick making animated gifs not animated?

Tags: php, imagick

I'm sending imagick an image and when it is an animated gif it removes the animation and leaves on a single still. Is this because of the resize code? Or is it something inherent in the imagick library? Below is my code, what is wrong here?

```
            if (isset($_FILES["image"])) {
                $allowed_ext = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");
                $file_name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
                $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode(".", $file_name)));
                $file_size = $_FILES["image"]["size"];
                $file_tmp = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];

                // verify extension
                if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed_ext) && $file_size < 2097152) {
                    // check if image needs scaling
                    $img = new imagick($file_tmp);
                    $img_size = $img->getImageGeometry();

                    $partyCommentErrors .= "<li>Width: ".$img_size["width"]." | Height: ".$img_size["height"]."</li>";

                    if ($img_size["width"] > 600 || $img_size["height"] > 600) {
                        // resize image
                        $img->resizeImage(600, 600, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9, true);
                    }

                    $img_size = $img->getImageGeometry();
                    $img->writeImage("imgs/commentpics/".$id.".".$file_ext);

                    // update database
                    $qry = "UPDATE comments SET thereisimg=1, imgtype='".$file_ext."', imgwidth='".$img_size["width"]."', imgheight='".$img_size["height"]."' WHERE id=$id";
                    mysqli_query($dblink, $qry);

                } else {
                    $partyCommentErrors .= "<li>File type must be jpg, jpeg, png, or gif</li><li>File size must be less than 2 megabytes.</li>";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Just a little question back: Why do you think that code must create an animated gif in the first place?

Comment: It's not creating an image. It's taking an image from a form and getting its dimensions, then resizing it if necessary and saving it. Sorry probably should have made that clear.

Comment: Well, again, why do *you* think it must save as an animated gif then?

Comment: Well why wouldn't it? If the input image is an animated gif then surely the output image should be the same file only resized, right? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Because animated gifs are not stored as full images, but instead are stored as the differences between the frames of the animation, you need to call `Imagick::coalesceImages` to be able to modify the images contained in the Gif.

After modifying them, you then need to call `Imagick::deconstructImages` to generate the new set of differences between the frames, to be able to save them out as an animated Gif.

```
<?php
$imagick = new Imagick("original.gif");

$format = $imagick->getImageFormat();
if ($format == 'GIF') {
  $imagick = $imagick->coalesceImages();
  do {
     $imagick->resizeImage(120, 120, Imagick::FILTER_BOX, 1);
  } while ($imagick->nextImage());
  $imagick = $imagick->deconstructImages();
  $imagick->writeImages('new_120x120.gif', true);

  // can be added some more gifs
  $imagick = $imagick->coalesceImages();
  do {
     $imagick->resizeImage(100, 100, Imagick::FILTER_BOX, 1);
  } while ($imagick->nextImage());
  $imagick = $imagick->deconstructImages();
  $imagick->writeImages('new_100x100.gif', true);
}

$imagick->clear();
$imagick->destroy();
```

Or, more briefly:

```
<?php 
$image = new Imagick($file_src); 

$image = $image->coalesceImages(); 

foreach ($image as $frame) { 
  $frame->cropImage($crop_w, $crop_h, $crop_x, $crop_y); 
  $frame->thumbnailImage($size_w, $size_h); 
  $frame->setImagePage($size_w, $size_h, 0, 0); 
} 

$image = $image->deconstructImages(); 
$image->writeImages($file_dst, true); 
?>
```

Comment: I have some animated gifs that have identical frames for a pause, when I resize and deconstructImages, I lose all identical ones and the gif play faster with no apparent pause... from 62 frames I get 25

Comment: @CristianRusu ask your question as a new question, or open a bug report if you really think it's a bug: https://github.com/Imagick/imagick/